# How to extract nested json with SQL

Tags: sql, json, nested

I have a table name ‘my doc’. And there is a column which is a nested json called ‘element’. The structure is as below.

I want to extract `league_id`. How to make it with SQL? Thanks

```
{
   “api”: {
      “Results
```

Comment: Please don't screenshot your codes. Copy & paste to your question and format it properly please.

Comment: Hey i can not find your column. you should present your codes smarty.

Answer (score 0):

Different SQL implementations have different standards..

E.g. mysql can handle a JSON field in their table

```
-- returns {"a": 1, "b": 2}:
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('a', 1, 'b', 2);
```

https://www.sitepoint.com/use-json-data-fields-mysql-databases/